# Localhost Connection Throttled at 1Gbps

Tags: networking, azure, mongodb

I am using mongorestore to restore a db to a localhost server on a Windows VM

The connection uses mongodb://localhost:27017

Resource Monitor shows that the speed of the restore is limited at 1Gbps and seems to be the limit of the network card or localhost connection.

Is it possible to speed up this bottleneck through a different VM, Network setup, or other means?
[image]

Comment: Why do you believe network is the bottleneck? What does CPU, memory and disk look like?

Comment: If you are importing to localhost that mean you have the back on the same server so might be a HDD bottleneck and not network because you are using a localhost connection

Comment: How do you nic settings look like?`Get-NetAdapter | Select-Object *`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Older versions of Windows had poor localhost performance. So poor in fact it was significantly improved around ~2015 by adding SIO_LOOPBACK_FAST_PATH feature. This was even adopted by some vendors (JDK 8 in 2017 for example).

Now Microsoft claims that current Windows localhost performance is improved enough so that SIO_LOOPBACK_FAST_PATH is deprecated and will be converted into a no-op in a future release. (Also it bypasses some parts of WFP so not optimal).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57610475/sio-loopback-fast-path-replacement

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/sio-loopback-fast-path

https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8175228

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/sio-loopback-fast-path

https://github.com/libuv/libuv/issues/489